# Activity can't start (maybe a declaration error)

Tags: android, android-activity

)

I'm using HoloEverywhere and ActionBarSherlock in my app and would like to Launch an activity but when I select the activity from my launcher, the app starts only in black and Exits directly.

Here's the activity I'd like to start:

```
public class SocialActivity extends SherlockActivity {

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social);


    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.SocialwebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.connectme.bugs3.com/messenger.html");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SocialWebViewClient());
}
```

}

and here's how it is declared in the Manifest (because I want it to be a second launcher activity):

```
<activity
        android:name="org.quantumbadger.redreader.activities.SocialActivity"
        android:label="@string/social_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/messenger"
        android:taskAffinity="org.quantumbager.redreader.activities.SocialActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I don't know exactly where my error is but I think it's the SocialActivity extends SherlockActivity.

Has somebody an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the super method of onCreate.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social);
```

to

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social);
```

To understand what is the error and where is, you should read the logcat.
And next time you post an android question, you should provide logcat too.